# How to get student t parameters from data set?

Tags: python, statistics

I'm new to coding in python, and want to get parameters from a data set that I know from theory is most likely t-distributed. The first method I tried was using t.fit(). To double check the results I also used st.stats.describe(), and noticed I got different results. I also used t.stats() to get the moments "mvsk". I'm not sure what the different functions do, and which results to trust. The parameters are later going to be used in a Monte Carlo Simulation. Can somebody explain the different methods, and what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm,t
import scipy.stats as st
import pandas as pd
import math


SP = pd.read_excel('S&P+sectors.xlsx',
                parse_dates=['date'],
                index_col='date')['.SPX']                   

rets = np.log(SP).diff()
rets = rets.dropna()

t.fit(rets)
print("Parameters from t.fit: ", t.fit(rets), "\n")

d = st.stats.describe(rets)
print(d, "\n")
print("Standard Deviation from st.stats.describe : ",np.sqrt(d[3]), "\n")

mean, var, skew, kurt = t.stats(t.fit(rets)[0], moments='mvsk', 
        loc =  t.fit(rets)[1], scale = t.fit(rets)[2])

print("mean, std.dev, skew, kurt: ",mean,np.sqrt(var),skew,kurt)
```

Output:

```
Parameters from t.fit:  (2.563005821560674, 0.0005384408493821172, 0.006945103287629065) 

DescribeResult(nobs=4767, minmax=(-0.09469514468085727, 0.10957195934756658), mean=0.00011244654312862343, variance=0.00014599380983290917, skewness=-0.21364378793604263, kurtosis=8.494830112279583) 

Standard Deviation from st.stats.describe :  0.012082789819942626 

mean, std.dev, skew, kurt:  0.0005384408493821172 0.014818254946408262 nan nan
```

---

You can see that I get different means from the t.fit() and st.stats.describe(). The standard deviation is different for all three, and the skewness and kurtosis is also different. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference

SQRT(0.00014599380983290917) = 0.01208278982

One is variance, another is stddev

Ok, lets make it more descriptive.

Parameters from t.fit is what fitter think is best to put t-Distribution curve over set of sampled data.

DescribeResult produced variance, not stddev, so here we take square root of variance and get stddev, SQRT(0.00014599380983290917) = 0.01208278982. Then you compute stddev yourslef, and they are the same. Please remember, those values (like stddev, variance, mean) are taken from sampled data.

On the last line you compute DISTRIBUTION mean and stddev, most likely by applying formulas or doing numerical integration. They are ALWAYS different from sampled mean or sampled stddev. Fitting is trying to fit everything (all moments) at once, minimizing some or another error. It works other way around as well - if you come with distribution parameters, compute distribution mean, stddev, and then run some sample and compute sampled mean/stddev, they would be different from distribution ones. Only in case of infinite sample szie you'll reach agreement between distribution moments and sampled moments.